# How is the file size of a 3D .gltf model determined?

Tags: 3d, blender, aframe, gltf

This is not tied to a problem, but I was looking at diferent .gltf files that had the same or similar number of triangles in them and different file sizes. How does this happen and why?

Additionally, how do texture files tie into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#gltf-basics —

[image: diagram displaying purpose of .gltf (nodes and materials) .bin (geometry and animation) and texture files]

The geometry data (vertices and face indices) are not stored in the `.gltf` file if it has external binary '.bin' resources, and larger meshes will not make that `.gltf` file larger. However, having a large number of meshes, scene nodes, or materials (say, 1000s) would increase the size of the file gradually, because they all have to be listed and described. Likewise, textures can be stored externally and not much is kept in the `.gltf` except a list of those textures.

It's also possible to pack all of these resources into a single plaintext `.gltf` or binary `.glb` archive, with no external file dependencies. In that case, all of the above contribute to the total filesize.